# Extract partial content using regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract **14-A2F** out of **P‡GUID/CT-14-A2F2/SU-14-1F939**(match til `/`) or **P‡GUID/CT-14-A2F2**(match at the end of the line)

```
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("CT-[a-zA-Z0-9-\\-]+(/|\\z)");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("P‡GUID/CT-14-A2F2/SU-14-1F939");

    matcher.find();
    matcher.group();
```

no success so far, is there something wrong with my pattern or I this is not the use case for matcher.group

Comment: as per your current regex, it'll match all characters till `/` or end of string. is that the requirement? or ..is it 3 characters after `-`.

Comment: match till `/` or end of string is the requirement

Comment: You should change `[a-zA-Z0-9-\\-]` to `[^/]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex `CT-[a-zA-Z0-9-\\-]+(/|\\z)` you match `CT-[a-zA-Z0-9-\\-]+` and then you use a capturing group for the last part which in this case will capture a forward slash. If you use `matcher.group();` you will get the whole match which will be `CT-14-A2F2/`

You could shift the capturing group to the first part and then in the code refer to the first capturing group:

[`CT-([a-zA-Z0-9-\-]+)(?:/|\z)`](https://regex101.com/r/RIjdD5/1/)

In Java:

`CT-([a-zA-Z0-9-\\-]+)(?:/|\\z)`

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("CT-([a-zA-Z0-9-\\-]+)(?:/|\\z)");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("P‡GUID/CT-14-A2F2/SU-14-1F939");

matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // 14-A2F2
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/HYLA9237)

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex: `(?<=CT-)[a-zA-Z0-9-\\]+(?=\/|$)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HH0Hh1/1)

Comment: note: ? The preceding token is not quantifiable in the demo

Comment: not sure if I understood your comment. `?` is part of the regex syntax for look ahead and look behind assertions

Comment: yup but there is pattern error on https://regex101.com/r/HH0Hh1/1 Still figuring out why it still returns false in matcher.find()

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match everything between two forward slashes.
take the group out of it which is in parenthesis.

```
/([^/]*)/
```

you don't need to escape forward slash